# ReferenceError: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to use redux with react-native. I have created a fetch post data example app , then I just wanted to use with mapDispatchToProps method. I read the documentation and look at some tutorial, it looks similar.

**Problem is when I try to use mapDispatchToProps its return error:**

*ReferenceError: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: dispatch*

An error appears in HomeScreen

My Home Screen

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getPosts } from '../actions/index';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  state = {
    data:[],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPosts()
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

      </View>
    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps  (state)   {
  return {
    posts: state.posts
  };
};

function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch)   {
  return {
    getPosts: () => {
      dispatch(getPosts())
    }
  };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen)
```

My Store

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

export default store = createStore(rootReducer);
```

My Action

```
import { GET_PGET_POST_LOADING,GET_POST_RECEIVED,GET_POST_ERROR } from './actionTypes';
import { GET_POST_URL } from '../api';

export const getPosts = () => {
    dispatch({
        type: GET_POST_LOADING
    });
    fetch(GET_POST_URL).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        dispatch({
            type:GET_POST_RECEIVED,
            payload:data
        })
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

My Reducer

```
import { GET_POST_LOADING, GET_POST_RECEIVED, GET_POST_ERROR } from '../actions/actionTypes';

const Post = (state = { posts: [] , loading: true }, action) => {
    console.log(action);
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_POST_LOADING:
            return { 
                ...state,
                loading: true 
            }
        case GET_POST_RECEIVED:
            return {
                loading:false,
                posts: action.payload
            }
        case GET_POST_ERROR:
            return state;
    default:  return state;
    }
}

export default Post;
```

My Appjs

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading, Asset, Font, Icon } from 'expo';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store/index';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoadingComplete: false,
  };

  render() {
      return (
        <Provider store={store}>
         <View style={styles.container}>
          {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
          <AppNavigator />
        </View>
        </Provider>

      );
  }
}
```

I'm new about Redux, where I'm missing?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's no reference to `dispatch` in `dispatch({
        type: GET_POST_LOADING
    });`. You might want to look at redux-thunk.

Comment: Are you even using `redux-thunk`?

Comment: Thank for your comments. I searched and I realized that I need to use redux-thunk but I fixed a problem with using redux-axios-middleware. But I don't understand why I can't use fetch method in action?

Comment: Action creators should return plain objects. If you used axios or any function - it becomes asynchronous because it returns a promise instead of a plain object. Using `redux-thunk` or similar middlewares solves this very problem.